# Will AES-GCM smaller sized tag (mac) be included in larger sized tag

Tags: mac, aes-gcm

I want to make sure that I understand AES-GCM correctly:

If I have:
**key1, plaintext1, iv1, adata1** and requset tag size of 96 bits, and tag size of 128 bits, will the **first 12 bytes** of the 128 bits tag equal 96 bits tag?

Comment: You may want to note that your question is equivalent to asking whether the default for GCM if asked to produce smaller tags is to truncate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, that's what the standard mandates.**

First we need to note that if you fix a key and an IV, then AES-GCM becomes fully deterministic, that is the same input will yield the same exact output.

Then we look into the standard, [NIST SP800-38D (PDF)](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf), and look at the way the tag is generated.

$$T=\operatorname{MSB}_t(\operatorname{GCTR}_K(J_0,S))$$

which effectively tells us that the $t$ most significant bits of the tag output (which is the same for both invocations) are to be used for the tag.

Then we look up the semantics of the $\operatorname{MSB}_s(X)$ function which are:

> The bit string consisting of the $s$ left-most bits of the bit string $X$.